# Code will not compile using Eigen library syntax issue perhaps?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, syntax, eigen

```
#include <iostream>
#include </Eigen/Dense>

using Eigen::MatrixXd;

int main()
{
  MatrixXd m(2,2);
  m(0,0) = 3;
  m(1,0) = 2.5;
  m(0,1) = -1;
  m(1,1) = m(1,0) + m(0,1);
  std::cout << m << std::endl;
}
```

When I compile I get this error test.cpp:2:23: error: Eigen/Dense: No such file or directory

However Eigen/Dense does exist my cpp file is in the directory in which /Eigen is in. Can anyone help?

Comment: Try removing leading slash: `#include <Eigen/Dense>`. Can you post the command you used to compile this?

Comment: I tried that I'm just running g++ -I / test.cpp

Comment: `g++ -I . test.cpp` with `#include "Eigen/Dense"`.

Answer (score 3):

Changing from:

```
g++ -I / test.cpp

#include <Eigen/Dense>
```

to:

```
g++ -I . test.cpp

#include "Eigen/Dense"
```

corrected this.